# How to generate 3 circles where all the 3 circles are of different classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is how I have generated 2 circles with classes 0 and 1. Can anyone help me in generating 3 circles with different classes?. I have used the default function from scikit learn to create 2 circles. Is there any possible way to create 3 circles in scikit learn?

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons, make_circles, make_classification
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame
from bokeh.colors.groups import blue
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

# generate 2d classification dataset
#X, y = make_moons(n_samples=1000, noise=0.1)
#X, y = make_circles(n_samples=1000, noise=0.1, factor=0.3, random_state=2)
# make the circles linearly separable
#X[:,1] = (np.multiply(X[:,0], X[:,0]) + np.multiply(X[:,1], X[:,1]))

# make blobs
X, y = make_circles(n_samples=1000, random_state=3, noise=0.04)



#X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=2, n_classes=2, n_redundant=0, n_informative=2,
#                             n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=1)
# scatter plot, dots colored by class value
df = DataFrame(dict(x1=X[:,0], x2=X[:,1], label=y))
colors = {0:'red', 1:'blue'} #, 2:'green'} # Add another color for 3 classes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
grouped = df.groupby('label')
for key, group in grouped:
    group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='x1', y='x2', label=key, color=colors[key])
#   group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='x1', y='x2', label=key, color=colors[key], xlim=[-3,3]) #for nonlinear mapping


export_csv = df.to_csv(r'blobs.csv', index = None, header=True)
print(df)

plt.savefig("blobs.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `make_circles` function, you can control the ratio of the inner circle to outer circle using `factor=` . A simple solution is to make 2 datasets with different ratios and combining them, for example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X_small, y_small = make_circles(n_samples=(250,500), random_state=3, 
noise=0.04, factor = 0.3)
X_large, y_large = make_circles(n_samples=(250,500), random_state=3, 
noise=0.04, factor = 0.7)
y_large[y_large==1] = 2
```

Combine them:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([X_small,X_large]),columns=['x1','x2'])
df['label'] = np.hstack([y_small,y_large])
df.label.value_counts()

1    500
0    500
2    500
```

Plot:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='x1',y='x2',hue='label')
```

[image]

Comment: I think this would help. But can you please explain your code in a little more detail?

Comment: which part is not clear?

Comment: why have you used n_samples=(250,500) instead of just using n_samples=500 for 500 points.

Comment: It's just for convenience, I used the first call of `make_circles` to generate 250 samples of the inner circle(class 0), 500 samples of outer circle (500), then same thing for the 2nd call. this way we can merge the class0 samples and have the sample number of class 0,1,2

Comment: this way, you would have exactly 500 samples of class 0 (250 from the first call of make_circles, 250 from the 2nd call), 500 samples of class 1 and 500 samples of class 2 (the largest circle)

Comment: Okay, I understand now.